# Why doesn't the javascript code work when I open the website

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-directions-api

I am a JavaScript beginner, but I'm trying to put a route on a google maps with the Google Maps Directions API and Google Maps Javascript API. If I start the website it doesn't show me any route, but if I execute the commands at the Google Chrome Console it shows me the route. [picture from the Google Chrome Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/egRJE.png)

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="map" style="width:100%;height:500px;"></div>
           <script>
                function requestRoute(origin1, origin2, destination1, destination2, waypoints) {


                            var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
                            var myoutput = [];

                            var request = {
                                    origin: new google.maps.LatLng(origin1, origin2),
                                    destination: new google.maps.LatLng(destination1, destination2),
                                    waypoints: waypoints,
                                    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
                                };

                                directionsService.route(request, function (result, status) 
                                {   if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) 
                                        {
                                        for (var x = 0; x < result.routes[0].legs.length; x++){
                                        var myRoute = result.routes[0].legs[x];

                                        for (var i = 0; i < myRoute.steps.length; i++) {
                                                for (var j = 0; j < myRoute.steps[i].lat_lngs.length; j++) {
                                                    myoutput.push(myRoute.steps[i].lat_lngs[j]);
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }

                                    } else{
                                    alert(status)
                                    }
                                });

                            return myoutput;                        




                        };

                    function processWaypoints(waypoints) {
                            var myarray = waypoints;

                            var myoutput = []

                            for (var x = 0; x < waypoints.length; x++){
                                myoutput.push({location: new google.maps.LatLng(myarray[x][0], myarray[x][1]), stopover: false});
                            };

                            return myoutput;
                    };



                function initMap() {

                    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                      zoom: 2,
                      center: {lat: 12, lng: 15},
                      scrollwheel: false 
                    });




                var waypoints1 = processWaypoints([[-34.6036844, -58.3815591]]);
                var points1 = requestRoute(-33.4488897, -70.6692655, -24.7821269, -65.4231976, waypoints1);

                var routLine1 = new google.maps.Polyline(
                                {
                                    path: points1,
                                    strokeColor: "#FFC107",
                                    strokeOpacity:0.8,
                                    strokeWeight:4
                                }
                            );

                routLine1.setMap(map);




                }
           </script>

            <script async defer
            src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key='MyGoogleMapsAPIKey'&callback=initMap">
            </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Has anybody an idea what is wrong in my code?

Comment: You are not calling any of your functions

Comment: @Lixus `callback=initMap` they are in the google maps script tag :)

Comment: `but if I execute the commands at the Google Chrome Console it shows me the route.` But  you do not execute the commands in your shown code

Comment: you're example is working just fine on my machine

Comment: @Denny the code is being hit? [look at the dev console](https://jsbin.com/hosekukala/edit?html,output)

Comment: @Denny, look at the last script tag, it have a param called `&callback=initMap` on the url requested by the script. So, it will call the function initMap on load finish. And initMap is the function that is initializing  the map.

Comment: @Florian Kittelmann, just try something that looks really silly, is your browser minimized?, Try to add fixed with to the map, for example: `<div id="map" style="width:500px;height:500px;"></div>`

Comment: The directions service is asynchronous, you can't return anything from the callback function of an asynchronous call (you need to use the returned data in the callback function when/where it is available).  [Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/5Ln3p5xb/)

Comment: @Denny that's because their `requestRoute` function is calling an async resource and they're running it synchronously and returning `myoutput` which will always be `[]`. Not because they're _not executing the commands_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you're having is that the directionsService call is asynchronous. at the time `myoutput` is returned from `requestRoute` it is still an empty array. I restructured:

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="map" style="width:100%;height:500px;"></div>
       <script>
            var map;
            function requestRoute(origin1, origin2, destination1, destination2, waypoints) {


                        var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
                        var myoutput = [];

                        var request = {
                                origin: new google.maps.LatLng(origin1, origin2),
                                destination: new google.maps.LatLng(destination1, destination2),
                                waypoints: waypoints,
                                travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
                            };

                            directionsService.route(request, function (result, status) 
                            {   if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) 
                                    {
                                    for (var x = 0; x < result.routes[0].legs.length; x++){
                                    var myRoute = result.routes[0].legs[x];

                                    for (var i = 0; i < myRoute.steps.length; i++) {
                                            for (var j = 0; j < myRoute.steps[i].lat_lngs.length; j++) {
                                                myoutput.push(myRoute.steps[i].lat_lngs[j]);
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }

                                    plotRoute(myoutput);

                                } else{
                                alert(status)
                                }
                            });

                        // return myoutput;                        




                    };

                function processWaypoints(waypoints) {
                        var myarray = waypoints;

                        var myoutput = []

                        for (var x = 0; x < waypoints.length; x++){
                            myoutput.push({location: new google.maps.LatLng(myarray[x][0], myarray[x][1]), stopover: false});
                        };

                        return myoutput;
                };



            function initMap() {

                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                  zoom: 2,
                  center: {lat: 12, lng: 15},
                  scrollwheel: false 
                });




            var waypoints1 = processWaypoints([[-34.6036844, -58.3815591]]);
            requestRoute(-33.4488897, -70.6692655, -24.7821269, -65.4231976, waypoints1);




            }
            function plotRoute(points1){


                var routLine1 = new google.maps.Polyline(
                                {
                                    path: points1,
                                    strokeColor: "#FFC107",
                                    strokeOpacity:0.8,
                                    strokeWeight:4
                                }
                            );

                routLine1.setMap(map);
            }
       </script>

        <script async defer
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAJLxeMko3jmj7ImPv96sVt-eyP7FtixQc&callback=initMap">
        </script>
```

it's not pretty, but you get the idea.

Comment: @dgeare The question looks similar like mine but in my question I need to get the response through another function call. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53210241/calling-a-google-directiction-service-doesnt-return-the-result

Comment: @dgeare can you answer my question